# Java: Adding graphic items to a frame

Tags: java, graphics, awt, frame, addition

My issue is that I have two objects that have a "public void paint(Graphics pane)" class, and I want to add them both to a frame. I have the code in place to do so, but only the last die I add actually shows up. Any solutions / additional info you need to see?

The Add code:

```
public void addDice(Die userDie, Die computerDie) {

     gameFrame.add(userDie);
     gameFrame.add(computerDie);

}
```

And yes, the method is called and receives the two dice objects, and the object's class does extend "Component".

gameFrame is a Frame made with

```
Frame gameFrame = new Frame();
```

This is an AWT application, not Swing.

Thanks!

Comment: We need to see more code to help. What is gameFrame? How do you create it?

Answer (score 1):

Is this a Swing application (JFrame) or an AWT application? Or something else? You may need to change your "Frame's" layout to GridLayout so that it can show both components. You will want to read up on use of the layout managers [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)